# Can anyone tell me how to align metro UI CSS Layout tiles

Tags: jquery, css, html, dom

The thing is that I have a pair of tiles of span 4 & span 5 in the first row and in the next one i got a large tile of span 9 ... but everything is misaligned some idea of why it is happening???

I'm using Chrome 31 with JQuery 2.xx -- Metro UI CSS 2.0

The width of the grid is the default 940px..

```
<body class="metro">
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="board grid">

<div class="row">
<div class="span4 bg-red tile header">size 4</div>
<div class="span5 bg-red tile header">size 5 </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="span9  bg-cyan tile weather header ">size 9</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="span2  bg-pink tile weather header ">size 2</div>
<div class="span6  bg-yellow tile weather header ">size 6</div>
<div class="span1  bg-orange tile weather subheader ">size 1</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

"The Wrapper is blank"

Right now it look like this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2KdeNv2dTpxMU1NcF94eVBmeTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you post some code, a fiddle and/or what you've already tried? Otherwise its like trying to find a specific grain of sand on a beach :(

Comment: Blinded question with no code...

Answer (score 0):

you must add span to 12 grid in each row..

Comment: This happen https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2KdeNv2dTpxWG53Y2ZrVUs2V0U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: try you add offset each your class span..

<div class="span4 offset8 bg-red tile header">size 4</div>

Comment: That Box got aligned with the box before it but the others not even giving them offset to match the 12 columns

Comment: okk ,you should use a row in each column that you created, so that the display according to your purpose..

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem using a plugin called Gridster if you're interested here the link: [Plugin to design Metro UI style layout](http://gridster.net)It let you drag the blocks around the screen to until you get the position desired.  even you can decide if let the blocks draggable or not for the users.